# How to exclude some tables to be purged in DoctrineFixtures in Symfony 4?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4, fixtures, symfony-console

How can we exclude some tables (for example, country, city, etc) to be purged via doctrine:fixtures:load? Is there any yaml configuration file or sth else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such options was implemented recently in https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/pull/307

You could use `--purge-exclusions` option now. Enjoy!
E.g.

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction --env=test --purge-exclusions=regions --purge-exclusions=countries
```

You could read to how customize purging behaviour https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#specifying-purging-behavior

Be attention that this feature is available only since `3.4.0` release https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/releases/tag/3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

`php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append`

By default the load command purges the database, removing all data from every table. To append your fixtures' data add the --append option.

Source: [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-fixtures)

Comment: Edited now. Thanks!